# Using Pyomo GLPK in google cloud app engine

Tags: flask, gcloud, pyomo, glpk

I set up a Flask service local using pyomo glpk solver, and it runs correctly on my local machine.

But when I uploaded it to a GCloud App Engine, with the exact same virtual environment that worked locally, I got the error:

`RuntimeError: Attempting to use an unavailable solver.`

I've already downloaded the glpk windows version from the glpk website and used glpsol.exe path as an argument and that worked locally, but didn't work on my GCloud App Engine.

I ran `conda install -c conda-forge glpk` with the virtual environment activated, which did not help.

```
import pandas as pd
from pyomo.opt import SolverStatus, TerminationCondition
from pyomo.environ import *
import sys
...

solver=SolverFactory('glpk', executable='venv\\Library\\bin\\glpsol.exe')
```

This is the relevant part of my code. I've tried different glpsol.exe paths, with no success so far.

Does anyone know how to deploy a pyomo with glpk solver to a GCloud App Engine environment?

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to run a Windows executable on App Engine.

There's no Windows OS through the service..

Comment: That makes sense. But do you have any idea on how to make this work? Since the glpk solver is not automatically installed with pyomo library.

Comment: I don't. I'm unfamiliar with glpk.

Answer (score 0):

I didnt't get a solution to this problem, so I decided to use another solver library.